# memory leak in linux by delphi?

Tags: linux, delphi, memory

Sorry， Forgive my poor english !!!

I found a piece of code in the method CreateFormFromStrings in the System.Net.HttpClient unit 1720 line .

```
procedure THTTPClient.CreateFormFromStrings(const ASource: TStrings; const AEncoding: TEncoding;
const AHeaders: TNetHeaders; var ASourceStream: TStream; var ASourceHeaders: TNetHeaders);
        var
          LParams: string;
          LEncoding: TEncoding;
          I: Integer;
          Pos: Integer;
        begin
     // ******** Ignor some code 
          ASourceStream := TStringStream.Create(LParams, TEncoding.ASCII, False); 
          try
            ASourceHeaders := [TNetHeader.Create(sContentType,
              'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=' + LEncoding.MIMEName)] + AHeaders;  // do not translate
          except
            FreeAndNil(ASourceStream);
            raise;
          end;
        end;
```

So I took it out and tested it separately. I don't know if the memory leaked. Use valgrind tools to test，you will find:

[image]

Comment: Please take the time to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29323587) you question and format the code. And while you are at it, make the image visible or better copy/paste the messages in the question.

Comment: Are you sure we look at your complete `LinuxTest.dpr` with at least 28 lines?

Comment: Put the whole code inside a loop doing 1000 loops. Then look about the memory leak. If it is 1000 times the initial value, we have a problem. If it doesn't change, this simply mean that somewhere the RTL is allocating some memory for global item and do not free it before going back to the OS and we don't have any problem.

Comment: The leak report suggests there is an `AnsiString` being leaked when the RTL internally calls `LocaleNameFromCodePage()`. Nothing we can do about that here. [File a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero. The `TStringStream` is secondary, you can likely reproduce the leak by calling `TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes('')` by itself.

Comment: On the other hand, Delphi's RTL caches freed memory for reuse, so it is possible that the leak report is misleading and is being generated before cached memory has been released back to the OS. Delphi has its own [`ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown), have you tried it yet? Does it report the same leak?

Comment: windows is ok ,but linux test found this .

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). All of that Valgrind information is text, and can be copied and pasted directly into your post as such. That image is totally unreadable and useless. Images should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate the problem, and that is definitely not the case here. Please [edit] your question to remove the image and use text instead.